# Interfaces not showing up in Visual Studio Intellisense on Test Class

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am fairly new to development, and Visual Studio 2010.

I have a solution with a Test Project:

- In my solution, there are two projects: "TPS" and "TPS.Tests"
- In the TPS project, in the namespace "TPS.Models" I have defined a bunch of classes, and two interfaces.
- I have created a Test Class in the TPS.Tests project, and have added "using TPS.Models;"
- I attempt to implement the interface by typing it out (e.g. public class FakeObjectClass : IObjectClass), but it isn't recognised (so I can't get the auto-implement going, which would be handy as I have over 100 methods)
- Typing in the class, in Intellisense, I can see all the objects defined in my model, but none of the interfaces.

Google has been unusually silent on the search combinations I have tried.  I am hoping there is some simple explanation/fix?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't specified an access modifier when defining the Interface, it will default to internal and not be visible to other assemblies.

Make sure that you defined your interface as

```
public interface IMyInterface
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:
- Does your "TPS.Tests" project have a reference to the "TPS" project?
- Are your interfaces in the "TPS.Models" namespace? Putting the files in a sub-directory of the project, such as "Interfaces", can affect their namespace.
- Are the interfaces marked as `Public`?

Also, I would suggest using an Isolation (aka "Mocking" framework) to create your fake objects, such as [Moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/), [Rhino.Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx), etc, rather than rolling your own fake objects for most situations.